# How to set cache WebView when I using loadDataWithBaseUrl()?

Tags: android

```
    final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo active = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (active != null && active.isConnected()) {
        String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()
                .getAbsolutePath();
        webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(
                WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 0124 * 8);
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<html><head><title>Cache Test</title></head><body><p>This is Icon</p><br/><img src='http://google.com.us/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png'></body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    } else {
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<html><head><title>Cache Test</title></head><body><p>This is Icon</p><br/><img src='http://google.com.us/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png'></body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", ""); }
```

Manifest have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But when I open webview offline then webview return "Null". Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

See this http://alex.tapmania.org/2010/11/html5-cache-android-webview.html for an extended discussion that I think covers what you're trying to do.

Comment: supported link is broke